# Delete entity in many to many Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, sql-delete

I have a many to many association in Spring Jpa built with a composite primary key. My entities are Client and GunType and the bridge entity is Rental. And my problem is that I want to delete a rental(I want to keep the fetch type eager). The code runs without exceptions, but there is no result.

These are the entities:

```
public class Client extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    private String name;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client",
            cascade ={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Rental> rentalSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class GunType extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    private String name;

    private Category category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gunType",
                cascade ={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH},
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Rental> rentalSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class Rental implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "guntype_id")
    private GunType gunType;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;
}
```

And in the delete method in service I tried to remove the rental from both sets, but it still does nothing:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteRental(Long clientId, Long gunTypeId) {
        logger.trace("deleteRental - method entered; clientId = {}, gunTypeId={}", clientId, gunTypeId);
        Client client = clientRepository.findById(clientId).orElseThrow();
        Optional<Rental> rentalOptional = client
                .getRentalSet()
                .stream()
                .filter(rental -> rental.getGunType().getId().equals(gunTypeId))
                .findFirst();
        rentalOptional.ifPresent(
                rental -> {
                    client.getRentalSet().remove(rental);
                }
        );
        GunType gunType = gunTypeRepository.findById(gunTypeId).orElseThrow();
        rentalOptional = gunType
                .getRentalSet()
                .stream()
                .filter(rental -> rental.getClient().getId().equals(clientId))
                .findFirst();
        rentalOptional.ifPresent(
                rental -> {
                    gunType.getRentalSet().remove(rental);
                }
        );
        logger.trace("deleteRental - method finished");
    }
```

I also tried to make it with annotations like ophanRemoval or CascadeType.ALL, but those didn't change anything. Or is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to delete the rental entity. (This represents the database table row, which you want to delete in the join table)

Create a repository with a delete method, something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface RentalRepository extends CrudRepository {
    void deleteByClient_idAndGunType_id(Long clientId, Long gunTypeId);
}
```

Useful article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-delete

Comment: I have to do this without a repository

Comment: That's why it is pretty hard

Comment: What is the reason you resist from a repository?

Comment: That is the task of the university, I don't know why

Comment: In this case I think the problem is that you are modelling a a many-to-many association with 2 many-to-one mappings. From JPA's point of view, in this case there is no need for entity deletion (if you do not use cascade delete). I you'd had modelled with "classic" many-many (without modelling the join table with an entity), then your approach (removing entity from both sides) would work.  https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-the-best-way-to-remove-entities-from-a-many-to-many-association/

Comment: One workaround could work: create an other Client and GunType entity (ClientForAssociationDeletion and GunTypeForAssociationDeletion), create the many-to-many mapping (so there is no rental entity in this case). And if you have to delete Rentals, use these entites. In every other case, use the normal ones.